# How to modify the iPhone status bar on a jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

I want to create a tweak to add a text to the status bar. The text will be appended to the time label. So what is the the hooked class and method.

Comment: sure thing, the Apple has an `NSAccessToAllPrivateAPIsWhichNotAvailableAnyway` class, but unfortunately you won't be able to find the _Class Reference_ documentation, because – I guess – this class is strongly private entirely, I'm not even sure the Apple Team knows about it, but trust me, that does the trick for you!

Comment: @holex he's asking about a Cydia (jailbroken) iPhone. It might be possible.

Comment: @Kheldar, I'm not saying it is not possible, I'm just saying that he might never find such class or method published anywhere. :)

Comment: @holex I have to agree with you on that.

Comment: @holex & Kheldar are both wrong.  There are plenty of tweaks that modify the status bar directly (i.e. Zeppelin).  I don't know the name of the class, but if I find it I'll post it.


EDIT: It's probably either `UIStatusBarStateObserver-Protocol`, `UIStatusBarStateProvider-Protocol`, or `UIStatusBarStyleDelegate-Protocol`.  I could be wrong though.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot hook a status bar.
You can just change its style and hidden properties.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStatusBarStyle